# For loop not iterating as desired in Python

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop

I have a dataframe with emails and links to send.
The code snippet I am using to iterate over the list and send to each user its correspondent link is:

```
boton_list=[]
for arch, user in enumerate(df_enlaces['CorreoElectronico'].values):

  enlace=df_enlaces.set_index('CorreoElectronico').loc[user]['Enlace']
  
  conteo=0
  print(arch,user,enlace)
  
  while conteo<(len(enlace)):
    boton=f"""<a href={enlace[arch]} > <button style='background-color: orange'; border-color:blue> LINK </button> </a>"""
    boton_list.append(boton)
    conteo+=1
```

However, "print(enlace)" prints the following:

[image]

My dataframe looks like:

[image]

There are only two rows and one user (in this example) and returns 4 rows?

Futhermore, boton_list returns:

```
["<a href=link1 > <button style='background-color: orange'; border-color:blue> LINK </button> </a>",
 "<a href=link1 > <button style='background-color: orange'; border-color:blue> LINK </button> </a>",
 "<a href=link2 > <button style='background-color: orange'; border-color:blue> LINK </button> </a>",
 "<a href=link2 > <button style='background-color: orange'; border-color:blue> LINK </button> </a>"]
```

Not returning link1 which is the one corresponding to the first row.
There's something I am missing and I cannot figure out the way.

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code or error messages.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: `boton_list=[]` should not be in the loop. You reset the list on each row of the df.

Comment: Ok I placed boton_list outside but now prints 4 elements. How to make it to print just two? Link1 and Link2. See my EDIT

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you don't need to loop, just apply your format directly:

```
button_template = """<a href={}><button style='background-color: orange'; border-color:blue> LINK </button> </a>"""
df_enlaces['Enlace'] = df_enalces['Enlace'].transform(lambda c: button_template.format(c))
```

Now you can export this to list:

```
df_enlaces['Enlace'].to_list()
```

Or, if you want nested lists for multiple users/emails:

```
df_enlaces.groupby('CorreoElectronico').agg(buttons=('Enlace', list))['buttons'].to_list()
```

Comment: Elegant solution. But how would I slice the array depending on the user? Imagine there's an email "email2@example.com" and it only has link1